# Jest, Apollo Client different implementations

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, apollo-client, react-testing-library

Currently I have this working test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import AuditList from '../../../components/Audit';

jest.mock('@apollo/client', () => ({
  useLazyQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([
    jest.fn(),
    {
      data: {
        someTestingData: 'some Value'
      },
      loading: false,
      error: false
    }
  ])
}));

describe('Audit', () => {
  it('should render audit', () => {
    const rendered = render(<AuditList />);
    const getBytext = rendered.queryByText('my title');
    expect(getBytext).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But, I want to test different cases: when ´loading/error´ is true/false.

How can I make specific definitions of the mock for different ´it´?

EDIT: I tried this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import AuditList from '../../../components/communications/Audit';

jest.mock('@apollo/client');

describe('Audit', () => {
  it('should render audit', () => {
    useLazyQuery.mockImplementation(() => [
      jest.fn(),
      {
        data: {
          someTestingData: 'some Value'
        },
        loading: false,
        error: false
      }
    ]);
    const rendered = render(<AuditList />);
    const getBytext = rendered.queryByText('Auditoría');
    expect(getBytext).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But I get ´ Cannot read property 'mockImplementation' of undefined ´

Comment: What's the version of `@apollo/client`? I didn't reproduce your issue

Comment: @slideshowp2 3.5.5